# Understanding Bottom-up Dynamic Programming

Tags: dynamic-programming, computer-science

I'm trying to understand the [solution](https://leetcode.com/problems/minimum-cost-for-tickets/editorial/) for LeetCode 983.

I do understand the relation `dp[day] = Min(dp[day - 1] + costs[0], dp[day - 7] + costs[1], dp[day - 30] + costs[2]` and the fact that `dp[i]` represents the minimum cost traveling until day `i`

What bugs me is that, let's say `dp[day-7]` doesn't have to be a day we were traveling (i.e. it's not in days). It means (as I see it) that we can't just jump from that day to our current day.

So I'm kinda missing how it works as expected. I do understand that we carry `dp[day] = dp[day - 1]` if `day` wasn't a traveling day but I still don't understand why it's allowed.

I think the following test-case represents my confusion. On day 41, why are we allowed to look at day 41-30?

```
days = [1,2,3,4,41,42,43,44,45]
costs = [3, 500, 4]
```

Comment: Think of `dp[d]` as "the cost of meeting all your ticket requirements for journeys on or before day `d`". Do you agree that is a meaningful quantity when `d` itself is not a travelling day?

Comment: @slothrop, well yeah, because `dp[lastDay]` is what we want if that's the definition of `dp`

Comment: OK, so in your example, then `dp[34]` has a coherent meaning even though day 34 is not a travelling day. It's not a problem then to use `dp[34]` in the calculation of `dp[41]`.

Comment: @slothrop, honestly I'm still stuck with the thought that it's not valid since `34` isn't a travel day and we might have carried `dp[34]` from an earlier day in which we couldn't buy a 7-days pass since the gap is larger than 7 days.

Comment: Can you detail the scenario that you think would give incorrect results here? (btw, I should have said that the same argument goes for `dp[11]`. The calculation for `dp[41]` involves `dp[40]`, `dp[34]` and `dp[11]`, all of which are meaningful quantities.

Comment: Actually, let me ask a question about your thinking. Obviously in DP we iteratively calculate `dp[d]` for each `d` in turn. Are you thinking of that loop as a kind of day-by-day *simulation*, where in each iteration of the loop we make a decision about our strategy for a given day? That view doesn't really work, because for example we don't "know" whether we bought a 7-day pass on day 34 until we calculate `dp[41]`. The loop should just be thought of as a *mechanical procedure* for solving the mathematical recurrence relations that describe the scenario.

Comment: @slothrop, sort of. What did you mean by "ticket requirements"? you mean that `dp[i]` promises that I'll cover all the days in `days` until the day `i` with the minimum cost?

Comment: Exactly. So if a 7-day pass costs $Y, then the inference is "if I can cover my costs until day i-7 for $X, then I can cover my costs until day i for at most $X+Y". You can make similar inferences for the 1-day and 30-day passes.

Comment: @slothrop, I think I'm sort of getting it through some examples. Like `days=[1,100,101]` and `costs=[5,1,1000]`. When evaluating `dp[101]` we find out that we could have bought a 7-days pass for both days `100` and `101` by "coming from" day `94`

Comment: Exactly. The calculation at every point is purely backward-looking and doesn't use information about later days in the schedule. At the point you calculate `dp[94]` you don't need to know whether you will buy a 7-day pass on day 94: that just ends up being figured out in the later steps of the calculation. So you had maybe been thinking "when we calculate `dp[94]` we can't know whether we should buy a pass" - that's a correct observation, but it's not a problem - the overall calculation works through repeated backward-looking steps and never requires us to look forward in time.